# How to bind a Button to a Slider and a TextBox in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, slider, togglebutton

I have a ListView and one column of that ListView includes a Slider, a TextBox, and a Button. The Slider is binded to a Property (of type `double`) in my ViewModel. When I move the slider, the value in the TextBox is updated automatically. However, my Button does not work, yet. It is supposed to increment the value every time it is clicked. Does anyone have an idea how to add this functionality in XAML.

```
<GridViewColumn Width="345">
    <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Wert" Command="{Binding SortCommand}" CommandParameter="Value" />
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10">
                <Slider Name="slValue" Value="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay}" Minimum="{Binding MinValue}" Maximum="{Binding MaxValue}" TickPlacement="BottomRight" TickFrequency="{Binding StepSize}" Width="205" />
                <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=slValue, Path=Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" DockPanel.Dock="Right" TextAlignment="Right" Width="40" />
                <Button Name="IncrementValue" Width="40" Height="40" />
            </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

**EDIT:** Actually, I need to use a normal Button, not a ToggleButton. I just changed `ToggleButton` to `Button`.

Comment: I am not clear on the toggle button functionality. Are you saying it has to increment slider value when each time clicked?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want. And when the end of the slider is reached (value_[i] = maximum), then is should start from the beginning (value_[i+1] = minimum)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the buttons' EventTrigger to change the slider's value and the text box will be updated automatically.

```
 <ToggleButton Name="Toggle" Width="40" Height="40" >
            <ToggleButton.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ToggleButton.Click" >
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation By="1" Duration="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="slValue" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Value"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </ToggleButton.Triggers>
        </ToggleButton>
```

You may handle the button's click event and amend the value of the button's sibling slider:

```
 private void IncrementValue_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((((Button)sender).Parent as DockPanel).Children[0] as Slider).Value++;
    }
```

Here I assume that the slider is the first element of the dock panel, if you change its position you should use another index at `Children[0]`

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! It works; however, the problem is that I cannot change the slider anymore, after the toggle button has been clicked once.

Comment: I'm afraid the only way to unblock a property changed in a storyboard is to use code-behind, which doesn't make much sense in your case.

Comment: Isn't there an alternative to the storyboard?

Comment: Do you have an idea how this could be solved using code-behind?